# Why can't I make these divs stay apart no matter what the screen width is?

Tags: css

Both containers are inside the parent div slideshow. I want the divs to always stay apart no matter how narrow I make the window. I tried using margin but it just places each div in relation to the parent div, I also tried to use percentages for the positions of each div but I still didn't get it to work. Now I tried to use float left but now they are both on top of each other.

```css
.SlideShow {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24vh;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(37, 33, 37, 0.8);
}

.ImageContainer {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
}

.textContainer {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Hubble Telescope
  </title>
  <link href="Space.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Space.js">
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body onload="">
  <div class="SlideShow">
    <div class="ImageContainer" id="ImageContainer" onclick="pause()"></div>
    <div class="textContainer">
      <div class="centertext" id="textContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Please provide HTML

Comment: I done did that

Comment: You are `absolute` positioning the elements. Doing so, it makes the elements "popout" from main document and "take no space". Is there a reason to be absolute-positioned? If not, use [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here? Obviously as pointed out by others `position: absolute;` is not the way to do so - whatever that goal IS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex box. and you can use **gap** property of flex box to make the div's stay apart. you can also use **justify-content** and give it the value space-between. Try this code

```
 .SlideShow{
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    top: 24vh;
    left: 0%;
    background-color: rgba(37, 33, 37, 0.8);
}

.ImageContainer{
    height: 500px; 
    width: 500px;  
    background-color: orange;
}

.textContainer{
    color: white;
    width: 30%;    
    height: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. But I don't know why you used **transform** can you please explain

Comment: i used transform to center the divs vertically indise .slideshow

Comment: if you want that remove both the transform attributes and add the code align-items: center; to the SlideShow div

Comment: Did I answer you question?

Comment: Yea you answerd it thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Here I use a grid (removed all the `position: absolute;` as not really great with for this) to place the columns in a centered "slider" block.

I added three columns and an additional row to illustrate how one row can be in the center column; another in the second row but have a margin.

For your actual question I used a variable for the gap size between the rows (I assume you wanted rows but that was hard to tell - but easy to adjust from here)

```css
body {
  /* reset so all browsers use the same */
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* reusable values */
  --gap-size: 1.25em;
  --slide-container-size: 37.5em;
  --left-col-size: 6rem;
  --right-col-size: 6rem;
  /* just super-center the entire slide show container */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.slide-show-container {
  height: var( --slide-container-size);
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #33333380;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: var(--left-col-size) auto var(--right-col-size);
  grid-template-rows: auto 4em 4em;
  gap: var(--gap-size);
}

.image-container {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  background-color: orange;
}

.text-container {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid cyan 1px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.75em;
}

.tester-container {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF000040;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  height: 2rem;
  color: #FFFF00;
}

.center-text {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}


/*
.SlideShow {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24vh;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(37, 33, 37, 0.8);
}

.image-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="SlideShow slide-show-container">
    <div class="image-container" id="ImageContainer"></div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="center-text" id="textContainer">texty text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tester-container">
      <div class="center-text" id="textContainer">tester out text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```